# React, getting errors when using sass

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, node-sass, sass-loader

When I go to write style in some class (in SASS file), error occurs. My have  install node-sass. I do not understand error. I have given error screenshot below.

**1. Navbar.jsx**

```
import React from 'react'
import { images } from "../../constants";
import './Navbar.sass';

const Navbar = () => {
  return (
    <nav className='app__navbar'>
      <div className='app__navbar-logo'>
        <img src={images.logo} alt="logo" />
      </div>
      <ul className='app__navbar-links'>
        {["home", "about", "work", "skill", "contact"].map((item)=>(
          <li className='app__flex p-text' key={`link-${item}`}>
            {/* <div /> */}
            <a href={`#${item}`}>{item}</a>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </nav>
  )
}

export default Navbar;
```

**2.Navbar.sass**

```
.app__navbar {
  width: 100%;

  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

**3. package.json**

```
{
  "name": "frontend_react",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@sanity/client": "^3.1.0",
    "@sanity/image-url": "^1.0.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.2",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.3",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "framer-motion": "^6.2.6",
    "node-sass": "^7.0.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-icons": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "react-tooltip": "^4.2.21",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
```

**4. Errors**

[image]

Comment: The sass file itself is fine, so there is something breaking when compiling it. Maybe you should save/import it as `.scss` ? Or you can switch to using `npm install sass` which seems to be recommended: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-sass-stylesheet/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.sass` files are compiled with the old indented syntax. Rename your file to
`.scss` and try again. I hope this solution will help you.

Comment: Wow!!! It's working. Thank you so much! love you.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna use curly braces, you should rename your files to `.scss`. Also according to Create React App's [doc](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-sass-stylesheet/), you should be using the `sass` package instead of `node-sass`. For that run those lines in your terminal and you should be fine to go:

```
npm un node-sass --save
npm i sass --save
```

Comment: Thank you brother. My problem is (.sass files are compiled with the old indented syntax. Rename your file to .scss) 
Now It's ok.

Comment: sass and scss difference it was not known to me. Now I know. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove curly braces from your sass file and it should work. Note the difference between scss and sass. What you wrote in your sass file is scss syntax.

So this is exemplary code you can have in your file in this case:

```
.app__navbar
  width: 100%
  display: flex
  justify-content: space-between
  align-items: center
```

Comment: sass and scss difference it was not known to me. Now I know. Thank you so much.